# Difference between @Transactional and @TransactionAttribute

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I started persistence coding and I came across annotations such as `@Transactional` and `@TransactionAttribute`.  I understand the basic functionality of these two annotations and also that they can be used at both class level and at the method level.  What I would like to understand better is the difference between these two annotations.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**@TransactionAttribute** is for EJB3 beans.

**@Transactional** is for POJOs (for example Seam, Spring/Hibernate).

Comment: "@Transactional". Now it's for EJB too. "https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html"

Comment: How I understand `@Transactional` could be used with EJB only with bean managed transaction mode, not container managed. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

- `@TransactionAttribute` is meant for **EJB** beans.
- `@Transactional` is meant for **CDI** beans.

No, `@Transactional` should not be used for annotating EJB business methods. While [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html) suggests, it *may* be used for EJB, the EJB specs suggests it should not be used for EJBs *at present*.